# How to approximate the xth percentile for a large unknown quantity of number

Tags: algorithm, sampling, percentile, approximation

Recently came across this question on how to find the xth percentile for a given stream of numbers. I have a basic understanding of how this could be achieved if the stream was relatively small (can be stored into memory, sorted and the xth value can be found) but I was wondering how the percentile could be approximated if the stream of numbers is fairly large and the number of numbers is unknown.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without storing the numbers (not necessarily in memory though).

Comment: Do you know the rough distribution of the values? Or hard limits?

Comment: No, there is no clear indication of the distribution of the values apart from from the range in which the numbers will appear from. These values are essentially server response times and hence have been stated that some of the response times may appear slightly out of order (but responses that are too out of order can be discarded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to select uniformly `k` elements from the stream `S` and then approximate xth percentile of `S` with the xth percentile of these `k` numbers. `k` depends on how much memory do you have and how precise the approximation should be.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a code example to test the solution:

```java
// create random stream of numbers
Random random = new Random(0);
List<Integer> stream = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    stream.add((int) (random.nextGaussian() * 100 + 30));
}
// get approximate percentile
int k = 1000; // sample size
int x = 50; // percentile
// init priority queue for sampling
TreeMap<Double, Integer> queue = new TreeMap<Double, Integer>();
// sample k elements from stream
for (int val : stream) {
    queue.put(random.nextDouble(), val);
    if (queue.size() > k) {
        queue.pollFirstEntry();
    }
}
// get xth percentile from k samples
List<Integer> sample = new ArrayList<Integer>(queue.values());
Collections.sort(sample);
int approxPercent = sample.get(sample.size() * x / 100);
System.out.println("Approximate percentile: " + approxPercent);
// get real value of the xth percentile
Collections.sort(stream);
int percent = stream.get(stream.size() * x / 100);
System.out.println("Real percentile: " + percent);
```

The result is:

> Approximate percentile: 29
>
> Real percentile: 29

I got a pretty good approximation for every `x` i used and currently i don't see why it can't be suitable for your case.

Comment: So I am currently attempting reservoir sampling with the selected elements being stored into a arraylist. But, it seems that the approximation is still far off from the desired xth percentile. So, I was wondering if a change in data structure would perhaps optimize this further in anyway? Also, the stream elements are response times and so, although some of the response times may appear out of order; they generally are in a somewhat sorted order and responses that are too out of order can be discarded. Knowing this, is there a different sampling algorithm that would be better given this?

Comment: @Bruce , i've added a code sample to the answer. Currently i can't see why this approximation is not working for you. Maybe you can provide an example of the stream?